# Tesseract for android, wont compile, open_memstream.c Ubuntu11.04

Tags: android, android-ndk, tesseract

I have used the tool tesseract for android.
I have followed every step in the readme.
But when trying to use ndk-build i get the following:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/stdio/open_memstream.c', needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/stdio/open_memstream.o'.  Stop.
```

I have checked that the paths are correct (LEPTONICA,LIBJPEG,TESSERACT, +_PATH). and they are correct, also libjpeg does compile (its the first in the .mk file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downloading of the project from http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/
Did not work, neither me or my colleague got it to work.
but a new version is under sources. If you check out that one, you can install it just as the readme files says and it works.
http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/source/checkout