# Error in compiling tesseract

Tags: android-ndk, compiler-errors, android-2.2-froyo, tesseract, libjpeg

I'm compiling [tesseract-android-tools-1.00](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/) by using android-ndk r8b(Tesseract-android-tools contain the android tools for compiling tesseract OCR,Leptonica and [Jpeg](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/jpeg) libraries.)

The README file instructions say that the three libraries are to be put under "external" folder which is under the project folder(here "tesseract-android-tools-1.00" folder).
Then the folder structure would be :

tesseract-android-tools-1.00/external/libjpeg/

tesseract-android-tools-1.00/external/tesseract-3.00/

tesseract-android-tools-1.00/external/leptonlib-1.66/

*When I run **ndk-build** under project folder(tesseract-android-tools-1.00 folder),I got the following error.*

> G:\eclipse\ws\tesseract-android-tools-1.00>ndk-build
>
> Install        : libjpeg.so => libs/armeabi/libjpeg.so
>   make: *** No rule to make target `/jni/com_googlecode_lepttonica_android/stdio/open_memstream.c', needed by`obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/stdio/open_memstream.o'.  Stop.

Before this error,I've come through some errors such as "***No rules to make target..*", "***No target found..,needed by ..*".
I fixed the errors by modifing the content of **tesseract-android-tools-1.00/jni/Android.mk** file,
from...

> .........
>
> # TESSERACT_PATH :=
>
> # LEPTONICA_PATH :=
>
> # LIBJPEG_PATH := "
>
> .........

to...

> ............
>
> TESSERACT_PATH := external/tesseract-3.00
>
> LEPTONICA_PATH := eclipse/ws/tesseract-android-tools-1.00/external/leptonlib-1.66
>
> LIBJPEG_PATH := g:/eclipse/ws/tesseract-android-tools-1.00/external/libjpeg
>
> ...........

I've to do this because I'm using on Windows7 and cannot perform Linux commands as shown in README file...

> export TESSERACT_PATH=${PWD}/tesseract-3.00
>
> export LEPTONICA_PATH=${PWD}/leptonlib-1.66
>
> export LIBJPEG_PATH=${PWD}/libjpeg"

Note:I downloaded libjpeg from github ... as a tag of **android-2.2.3_r2.1-0**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088477/tesseract-for-android-wont-compile-open-memstream-c-ubuntu11-04?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tesseract-android-tools-1.00 file in the Downloads section is old and doesn't work.

Instead, you should clone the latest code from the repository using this command:

```
git clone https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/
```